# Program keeps putting out weird results

Tags: python, class, sockets, dictionary, methods

I am having a problem with my program where my server receives data that I am NOT sending from my client

```
Connection from: ('192.168.0.17', 58167)
data recieved : __UserLogin123__
User Login requested
James Green at recieve login
James Green in accessCodes
93
{93: ['James', 'Green']}
Found
User Found
3
data recieved : __QUIT____CHECK_SCORE__
Incorrect code received
done
Connection from: ('192.168.0.17', 58182)
data recieved : __UserLogin123__
User Login requested
James Green at recieve login
James Green in accessCodes
93
{93: ['James', 'Green']}
Found
User Found
3
data recieved : __QUIT____CHECK_SCORE__
Incorrect code received
```

the last "data recieved : **QUIT___CHECK_SCORE**" makes absolutely no sense, I use codes to access methods from classes which will send certain types of data telling the server if i want to (for example) add a user to a database, and it does this by accessing a dictionary storing methods with string keys.
Here is the "handler" and "main" from my client:

```
def Main():
    global s
    host = "192.168.0.17"
    port = 5000
    ID = "__UserLogin123__"

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    s.connect((host, port))
    s.send(str.encode(ID))
    setupCheck = s.recv(2048).decode()
    time.sleep(1)
    if setupCheck == "__dataReceived__":
        username = input("Enter username : ")
        password = input("Enter password : ")
        userDetails = (username, password)
        dataString = pickle.dumps(userDetails)
        s.send(dataString)

    access = s.recv(2048).decode()
    print(access)
    if access == "__ACCESS_GRANTED__":
        permissionLvl = s.recv(2048).decode()
        print(permissionLvl)
        if permissionLvl == "1":
            ClientUser = User(username,password)
        elif permissionLvl == "2":
            ClientUser = Admin(username,password)
        elif permissionLvl == "3":
            ClientUser = HeadAdmin(username,password)
        else:
            print("SOMETHING WRONG SOMETHING WROGN")
            time.sleep(3)
        handler(ClientUser)
    else:
        print("Incorrect details provided")


def handler(ClientUser):
    function_dict = {"__QUIT__": ClientUser.quit(), "__PLAY_GAME__":         ClientUser.playGame(),
                 "__CHECK_SCORE__": ClientUser.checkScore(),"__CHECK_USERS__": ClientUser.checkUsers(),
                 "__ADD_ASSIGNMENT__": ClientUser.addAssignment(),"__REMOVE_ASSIGNMENT__": ClientUser.removeAssignment(),
                 "__EDIT_ASSIGNMENT__": ClientUser.editAssignment(), "__ADD_USER__": ClientUser.addUser(),
                 "__EDIT_USER__": ClientUser.editUser(), "__REMOVE_USER__": ClientUser.removeUser(),
                 "__CREATE_GROUP__": ClientUser.createGroup()}

    while True:
        checkDataReady = s.recv(2048).decode()
        print(checkDataReady)
        if checkDataReady == "__dataExchangeReady__":
            print("Available Commands:")
            ClientUser.availableCommands()
            commandChoice = ""

            while commandChoice not in choices:
                while True:
                    try:
                        commandChoice = int(input("Please enter your choice (number) \n-> "))
                    except ValueError:
                        print("Please only enter integers")
                    finally:
                        if commandChoice > 14 or commandChoice < 0:
                            print("Please only enter one of the numbers listed")
                        else:
                            break

                commandChoice = choices[commandChoice]
                print(commandChoice)
                checkString = "Are you sure you want to : " + commandChoice + "? (Y/N) -> "
                check = input(checkString)
                if check.upper() == "N":
                    commandChoice = ""
            print("executing function")
            function_dict[commandChoice]
```

and here is some server side code that I think is affiliated with the problem:

```
def handler(conn, addr):
    print("done")
    print("Connection from: " + str(addr))
    dbSetup()
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        data = conn.recv(2048).decode()
        print("data recieved : " + data)
        if data == "__QUIT__" or not data:
            print("Connection closed")
            print("Connection Closed by",  addr[0], ":", addr[1])
            break
        elif data in accessCodes:
            accessCodesHandler(data)
        elif data in commandCodes:
            commandCodesHandler(data)
        else:
            print("Incorrect code received")
            break
        conn.send(str.encode("__dataExchangeReady__"))

    conn.close()

def accessCodesHandler(accessCode):
    if accessCode == accessCodes[0]:
        print("User Login requested")
        username, password = receiveLoginDetails()
        print(username,password, "in accessCodes")
        userCheck = getUser_InHash(username, password)
        if userCheck == True:
            userPermissionLvl = str(getUser_InUserDb(username,"")[2])
            print("User Found")
            conn.send(str.encode("__ACCESS_GRANTED__"))
            time.sleep(1)
            print(userPermissionLvl)
            conn.send(str.encode(userPermissionLvl))

        else:
            print("User not found")
            conn.send(str.encode("__AccessDenied__"))
    else:
        print("Head admin setup protocol executed")
        username, password = receiveLoginDetails()
        addUser_InHash(username, password, 3)
```

I can see no reason why my server would ouput "QUIT__CHECK_SCORE" as i dont send any data that says that explicitly, my error code for client side is:

```
Enter username : James
Enter password : Green
__ACCESS_GRANTED__
3
James
Green
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Green/Desktop/Py Proj/Project_Client.py", line 197, in <module>
Main()
  File "C:/Users/Green/Desktop/Py Proj/Project_Client.py", line 153, in Main
handler(ClientUser)
  File "C:/Users/Green/Desktop/Py Proj/Project_Client.py", line 161, in handler
"__ADD_ASSIGNMENT__": ClientUser.addAssignment(),"__REMOVE_ASSIGNMENT__":     ClientUser.removeAssignment(),
  File "C:/Users/Green/Desktop/Py Proj/Project_Client.py", line 37, in removeAssignment
    s.send(str.encode("__REMOVE_ASSIGNMENT__"))
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly         closed by the remote host

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Sorry if this isnt enough information, I really dont know what is wrong with the program. Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Please be aware that d = { 'a': funca() } actually invokes funca() and stores its return value as the value associated with the key 'a'. If you want to store the function itself, for later lookup and invocation, then use d = { 'a': funca }.

Comment: aww shizzle, that actually explains a lot, because some functions seemed to have been executed in my client side. This probably answers my question, thank you

Comment: If I could upvote this I would

Comment: I'll add it as an answer. It may not be the only problem in the code, but it certainly seems to be a significant one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dictionary initialization code is suspect.

The following actually invokes funca() and stores its return value as the value associated with the key 'a':

```
d = { 'a': funca() }
```

If you want to store the `funca` function itself, for later lookup and invocation, then use:

```
d = { 'a': funca }
```